# php sql server connection string .. different port

Tags: php, string, connection, xampp, sqlsrv

i change xampp port number 80 to 8012 after this connection getting failed.

```
$serverName = "test"; 
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"db_test", 
   "UID"=>"user_test", 
   "PWD"=>"test_pass"
); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);
```

how can i fixed it?

Comment: did you try $serverName = "test:8012";

Comment: no it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add server as

```
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress, 8012";
```

explained here on the official site:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Comment: what is instanceName?

Comment: how do you connect to the database via ms sql client?

Comment: '<?php 
 $serverName = "sql64\SQLEXPRESS,8012";
 $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"9020", "UID"=>"sas", "PWD"=>"passe");
 $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);

 if($conn){
  echo 'Connected!';
 }else{
  echo 'Not Connected!';
 }


 session_start();

?>'

Comment: is that not working? with $serverName = "sql64\SQLEXPRESS,8012";